# How can I find the similar non-zero connections between different levels of sparsity of the same network?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, deep-neural-networks

I am pruning a neural network (CNN and Dense) and for different sparsity levels, I have different sub-networks. Say for sparsity levels of 20%, 40%, 60% and 80%, I have 4 different sub-networks.

Now, I want to find the non-zero connections that they have in common. Any idea how to visualize this or compute this?

I am using Python 3.7 and TensorFlow 2.0.

After the convergence of a neural network following the random weight initialization, some weights/connections increase (magnitude), while other weights decrease. You can then prune the smallest magnitude weights. I want to compare the remaining weights for say two networks having the same level of sparsity of say 50%. The idea is to have an idea of which weights were pruned away and which weights/connections remain.

Comment: The paper [Visualizing the Hidden Activity of Artificial Neural Networks](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/306049229_Visualizing_the_Hidden_Activity_of_Artificial_Neural_Networks) (by Rauber et al.) could be useful. I haven't yet read it. If I read it, I may provide an answer to this question later.

Comment: edited question to add more information

Comment: Thanks! Now, it's definitely clearer!